# How Can I Fix My Infinite Loop So That It Runs Infinitely?

Tags: c, while-loop

I was trying to create a program that runs infinitely until you type "exit". When a user types "donate", the program will prompt "Great! How much?". The program will keep on asking to donate until the donation money is greater than $100 (the target). The program will also have to ask you to "work here", if the user types "work here", the program will display how much has been donated.
The issue is when I type "donate" below the target, the program stops after I type in the donation money. The same issue occurs when I type "work here".
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int total=0;
    int target=100;
    char descision[20];
    int amount=0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("***Welcome! Are you looking to donate or do you work here?\n");
        scanf("%s", descision);

        if(strcmp(descision, "donate") == 0)
        {
            printf("Great! How much? $");
            scanf("%s", amount);
            total += amount;
        }
        else if(strcmp(descision, "work here") == 0)
        {
            printf("Total donated so far: %d", total);
        }
        else if(strcmp(descision, "exit"))
        {
            printf("Bye!!!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        if(total > target)
        {
            printf("We already met our target but thanks!");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing `== 0` after one of the `strcmp`s.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. You should have gotten a warning on the `scanf` statement that tells you what you did wrong. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wdv8rEzcj

Comment: When you input "work here" to `scanf("%s", descision);` the variable gets `"work"` and `" here"` is kept in the buffer for the next read. **Always prefer to use exclusively `fgets()` for user input. Forget `scanf()` exists.**

Comment: You read a string into `amount` and then try to add `amount` to an `int`. This should provide you with a nice warning. If you are not getting a warning: enable compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Wrong format specifier for `scanf("%s", amount);`, should be `scanf("%d", &amount);`

Comment: @RaymondChen. How do I turn on compiler warnings in Code Blocks.

Comment: ’Menu’ →’Project’ →’Build Options’ [Picture](https://tgui.eu/resources/CodeBlocksProjectBuildOptions.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
        printf("***Welcome! Are you looking to donate or do you work here?\n");
        scanf("%19[^\n]", &descision[0]); // <-- you need to give base address ampersand of first cell

        if(strcmp(descision, "donate") == 0)
        {
            printf("Great! How much? $");
            scanf("%d", &amount); // <-- Give ampersand address character
            total += amount;
        }
```

Explanation of `scanf("%19s[^\n]", &descision[0]);`
Your decision array is of size 20, thus you need the last cell to accommodate `'\0'` called null termination which tells printf when string ends. Thus `"[19s]"` means read upto 19 characters(will discard any number of characters above 19 count, hence you will avoid issues of overwriting memory beyond the allocation/your expectation) and `[^\n]` means read until it finds `'\n'` i.e when you hit Enter Key '\n' is generated behind.

Comment: I tried that, but now it keeps on looping "***Welcome! Are you looking to donate or do you work here?" after I make a decision to "work here" and/or "donate".

Comment: P.S. Your help was not what I was hoping to accomplish

Comment: @zackBYE344 did you fix last else-if block by putting ==0 ? I think you forgot that. If not can you post your code again under title called "After Update". Will look into it.

Comment: adding "== 0"  fixed it.